# Laravel get old input with dot notation

Tags: php, laravel

My input name is as follows:
`<input name="settings[custom_plan.breakpoint1]"/>`

How can I retrieve the `old` input for it? As the dot notation works for the array of the input, but not in the actual name. So `old('settings[custom_plan.breakpoint1]')` is not working, and neither is `old('settings.custom_plan\.breakpoint1')` (escaping the dot is working in the validation notation).

How can I retrieve the old value for the input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `old()` for getting the whole array and then "manually" extract the value:

```
{{ old('settings')['custom_plan.breakpoint1'] }}
```

---

Unfortunately, there is no way to use the dot-notation for this. `old()` helper uses the `Illuminate\Support\Arr@get` method and there is the key piece of code:

```
foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
    if (static::accessible($array) && static::exists($array, $segment)) {
        $array = $array[$segment];
    } else {
        return value($default);
    }
}
```

As you can see, first thing it does is that it splits the key by dots, and then search for nested array-values. Therefore there is no escaping from parsing the dot in your input name as a separator.

Comment: I thought of that, but it makes quite inconvenient and ugly code to make checks like `<input value="{{ old('settings') ? old('settings')['custom_plan.breakpoint1'] : $custom_plan->breakpoint1 }}"/>` or similar (as initially `old('settings')` will return `null`, so I can't fetch an array item from that.

Comment: @Giedrius Yes, I agree. It would probably be best if you just avoided dots in input names (if that is, in your case, possible).

Comment: Yes it seems like the only solution now. I'll use that as a quick fix and see if I can find a solution or perhaps submit a pull request to fix this.